# GWT Super Dev Mode doesn't work with GQuery

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery, gwt-super-dev-mode, gquery

I used maven dependency to get GQuery lib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Added inheritance to `project.gwt.xml` file, namely:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.query.Query'/>
```

Super Dev Mode config in `project.gwt.xml` looks like:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
```

And after running Codeserver I try to turn Dev Mode on and get the following message:

[image]

If I remove GQuery from project, Super Dev mode starts to work again.

Is it possible to launch GWT Super Dev mode with GQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like something is wrong in your project.

GQuery works fine with DevMode and SuperDevMode, it seems like a configuration issue in your gwt.xml

Check that the GQuery inherits line is before the add-linker line. If it's ok, can you share a small project having this issue?

Comment: You are right. Super Dev mode was followed by GQuery. I've put GQuery before add-linker and everything started to work. Thank you a lot :)